# ulimit in test kitchen

Tags: ruby, centos, chef-infra, test-kitchen

The operating system is `Centos 7`, I am using `Test Kitchen 1.13.2` and `centos-7.2` default vagrant box.

I need nproc to be above a certain limit for one user, for this I modified `/etc/security/limits.d/20-nproc.conf` (Which overrides `/etc/security/limits.conf`) and added

```
myuser    soft    nproc    99999
```

However, after rebooting the VM created by kitchen and I log via `kitchen login` and run `ulimit -a` I see this:

```
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 1878
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 1024
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 1878
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

I am afraid there is something in the way Kitchen connects to the VMs it generates that does not load `limits.conf` configuration. Any idea how to be able to test this locally on Kitchen?

Answer (score 1):

When you login using `kitchen login` default user is `vagrant`, if you want to check limits for user `myuser`, run:

1. `sudo su -`
2. `su -l myuser`
3. `ulimit -a`

It works for me ;-)

Comment: `sudo su -l myuser` should do also and save a bash process and a context switch

Comment: The main problem is that if the user needs to have a certain ulimit set to a process start (Like Elasticsearch with nproc), the process fails on every kitchen run and I can't build tests around it running as it should.

It seems to be more an issue about how Chef impersonates the users that start a service. :(

Comment: Chef doesn't impersonate user, init script does. Maybe you don't create limit file early enough? However this is 'an issue' for another question.

Comment: Maybe you're right. Or maybe is more a question related with Vagrant as a Kitchen driver.

The strange thing here is that I don't face this issue when loading my policyfiles in real machines instead of the Kitchen-Vagrant's VMs.